# requiring math/base issues in Racket

Tags: racket, require

why does the first work, and the second not?

```
(require/typed (planet williams/science/random-source) [random-integer (Integer -> Integer)])
(require/typed math/base [random-integer (Integer Integer -> Integer)])
```

The second produces an error telling me that there is no such file or directory for math/base in my collects folder. Is it possible I am missing that from my racket distribution (v 5.3)? If so, for what reason? And how would I best resolve that?

Or am I just making a real bone-head mistake here? Sorry for all the noob questions...

I am basing my attempt here on http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/base.html?q=Random

Oh, and I'm running the 64 bit distro, I do believe, on OSX, if that's relevant.

Comment: aaaaand... looking at the release notes for v 5.3.2, I am guessing that I simply don't have that li'l bundle of math/base installed. I'm reinstalling and we'll see where that leaves us

Comment: BTW: you don't need to use `require/typed` for the `random-integer` function because the math library is written in Typed Racket. Just a `(require math/base)` will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not have the module installed. I was on 5.3, and the module existed only since 5.3.2

Comment: Sounds good!  Accept this answer when the system allows you to.  ;)